# Website broken after installing DSO

Tags: apache-2.2, php, dso

My website is broken after installing DSO, by DSO I mean the PHP handler that's supposed to speed up a website, here: http://boomshadow.net/tech/php-handlers/

First the website was working as expected.

Then, after requesting my hosting company to install DSO (in order to get APC running), my website isn't working.

### Edit

The problem is that it now shows a page full of warnings saying that included files were not found. Like this:

```
Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/mydomain/public_html/index.php on line 14

Warning: include(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mydomain/public_html/index.php on line 14
```

Line 14 looks like this :

`include ("include/header.php");`

I'm getting similar errors for all lines using the `include` command, and all of them were working perfectly fine before the DSO installation.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it and make my PHP code work aggain? There's nothing wrong with the code, it was working perfectly fine before the DSO installation. I've checked everywhere but I can't seem to figure out if installing DSO also requires some configuration changes.

Comment: This needs a lot more detail. Such as: What is DSO? What warnings did you receive?

Comment: DSO is a handler that speeds up PHP! http://boomshadow.net/tech/php-handlers/ It's quite well known. My site was working perfectly fine before installing it, and right after installing it, the website's broken. for someone who's familiar with DSO or other handlers, I'm sure this is a fairly simple configuration problem.

Comment: Oh, you mean mod_php. It is _a_ DSO, not _the only_ DSO. And it might be a fairly simple problem, but if you want a solution, **you will have to tell us what the problem is**.

Comment: i've edited the question - i hope it's clearer now?

Comment: Not at all. You still incorrectly refer to DSO, and you don't bother to show the messages you're receiving.

Comment: I differ! I do not believe this is not incorrect, I've seen it called DSO wherever I've seen it, even on the cpanel website and on my hosting company's support docs as well. Anyway I've clarified it and added the warning messages now.

Comment: Why is this on hold? Please open it. I really cannot add more to this question, this is all I know, and I'm sure someone familiar with PHP handlers will understand it immediately.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is on your server, and not in your code?

Comment: Because the code had no problems at all before installation! Also, I've edited the question now to include the line that's causing the error - I can't see anything wrong in it, it was working for years before the DSO installation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the permissions of the files. DSO operates as the Web Server and not as the User.
2. Hire a server administrator.